# Reorder a list based on order from another list of a different length

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

Given two lists:

```
listA = ['apples','bananas','peaches','orange']
ListB = ['peaches','apples']
```

How do I reformat listA so that the items that are in both lists appear in the order from listB.

For example:

```
Result = ['peaches','bananas','apples','orange']
```

The rest of the values should maintain their position.

Comment: I can't understand the question. The expected result does not seem to match the description of the task.

Comment: sure you want apples twice in your result and no peaches anymore ?

Comment: Neither listA nor ListB contain "apple" (without s), yet the Result has it. And both have "peaches" but Result does not have it.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel, I made a mistake, corrected now

Comment: What about the rest of the values? Is there any preference where they should appear in the list? How about sorting the listB value all to the front, and the rest in any arbitrary order to the end?

Comment: That is a **very** weird requirement. You basically want to ignore all the elements not in `ListB` and sort the remaining values but keep the ignored values in their original locations!?

Answer (score 4):

Create an iterator for list B, iterate through list A, if the item occurs in list B, read from the iterator, else use the item as is:

```
>>> a = ['apples','bananas','peaches','orange']
>>> b = ['peaches','apples']
>>> it_b = iter(b)
>>> [next(it_b) if i in b else i for i in a]
['peaches', 'bananas', 'apples', 'orange']
```

Optionally: first clean list B to only contain values occurring in list A.

Comment: optionally: build a set with the items of `b` first, to make `if i in b` faster.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a copy of `list_b` and insert the missing values at the appropriate places. If you have bigger lists there might be better options concerning the performance.

```
list_a = ['apples', 'bananas', 'peaches', 'orange']
list_b = ['peaches', 'apples']

result = list_b.copy()

for index, value in enumerate(list_a):
    if value not in list_b:
        result.insert(index, value)

print(result)
```